# iOS - messaging app send picture

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm working on a messaging app, I wonder how to get these effects when sending a picture (is there a library for this already since it's so commonly used in most messaging apps):

- After taking a picture and clicking the "Use" button, the messaging window will show a shaded image of the picture I'm trying to send, and shows the % uploaded

[image]

- After the image is fully uploaded, it shows the image without the shade

[image]

- If pressed the image it will show the full size

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do this you just need to keep track of the total size of the image and how much as been transferred. This will depend on how you're sending the image. I was using a socket connection and I sent the image like this:

Network packet - [(int)length of packet][image data]

As soon as the first byte had arrived I knew the size of the image. Then I kept track of the amount transferred so far. I then passed this information to a MBProgressHUD which has an option to show a percentage. [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)